# No imprime en pantalla después del if

Tags: javascript

En el siguiente ejemplo la línea:

```
document.write("<br> tu saldo es" )
```

No se ejecuta ni dentro ni después del `if`, sin embargo sí se ejecuta si la pongo seguida de la línea

```
document.write("has comprado el artículo " + nuevoArtículo).
```

¿Podrían ayudarme a encontrar el por qué? , Adjunto el código completo:

```
<script>
var credito=20,precio=10,nuevoArtículo="frasco de dulce",carrito;
if (credito >= precio) {
document.write("has comprado el artículo " + nuevoArtículo)//enseño compra
carrito += nuevoArticulo //introduzco el artículo en el carrito de la compra
credito -= precio //disminuyo el crédito según el precio del artículo
document.write("<br> tu saldo es" )
} else {
document.write("se te ha acabado el crédito") //informo que te falta dinero
window.location = "carritodelacompra.html" //voy a la página del carrito
}
document.write("<br> tu saldo es" )
</script>
```

Comment: Principales errores :  cerrar las líneas correctamente de cada Instrucción con `;` y además , la variable `nuevoArticulo` la declaras con tilde y en la concatenación con `carrito` lo haces sin la tilde.

Comment: Eliminando las tildes (en general deberías evitarlas) ya funciona. Imprime `<br> tu saldo es` dos veces.

Comment: Hola Joel: recien estoy comenzando con javascript y me indicaron que es opcional colocar los ";" al finalizar cada instrucción.Respecto a tu respuesta tenés razón! Muchas gracias! No veo la opción en mi navegador para aceptar tu respuesta.Saludos

Comment: jotaelesalinas agradezco tu colaboración.

Comment: @Lorena es opcional, pero más adelante cuando uses **Minimizadores**, verás que será necesario , posiblemente la pregunta se cierre dado que se debe a un error tipográfico. Saludos

Comment: Lo que dices que ocurre es porque eso es lo que hace tu código, te explico: `tu saldo es` se  imprimirá 2 veces cuando `credito` sea mayor o igual a `precio` en su defecto (tal vez ni lo percibas)  se imprimirá `se te ha acabado el crédito` y seguidamente se redirigirá la pagina a: **carritodelacompra.html** es por ello que parezca que no se imprime.. Comenta `window.location` y tal vez puedas entender lo que ocurre.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero sí entiendo lo que realiza el código, lo que no sabía era el por qué no imprimía lo que quería y era por lo que indicaron: la misma variable estaba escrita con y sin acento. gracias

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código te ayudara a entender un poco los errores que haz cometido, Saludos.. ;))

```js
credito=parseFloat(prompt("credito "));
precio=parseFloat(prompt("precio "));
var nuevoArtículo="frasco de dulce",carrito;
if (credito >= precio) {
document.write("has comprado el artículo " + nuevoArtículo);  //enseño compra
carrito += nuevoArtículo; //introduzco el artículo en el carrito de la compra
credito = (credito - precio).toFixed(2); //disminuyo el crédito según el precio del artículo
} else {
document.write("se te ha acabado el crédito"); //informo que te falta dinero
}
document.write("<br> tu saldo es " + credito)
setTimeout('window.location = "carritodelacompra.html"; //voy a la página del carrito',5000)
```